# Databricks notebook hardcoding

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks, cicd

I have a databricks and a storage account each for dev and prod environment. The code promotion from the dev to prod region is done through Azure DevOps CI/CD pipelines. While in dev, the target file path is configured to dev adls which should be changed to prod adls in prod environment. Is there a way that I can remove this hardcoding and implement the code promotion using DevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely achieve that.

In prod Databricks, just store them as environment variables (which can be set manually or with [cluster configure](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html)

Usually, I'll just set these variables:

- ADLS storage name
- Access keys

With that, you won't need to hard-code these variables in your code. Also, it's more secure that way.

Reference: https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-get-started.html#get-an-azure-adls-access-key

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't use this method since my access level to the workspace doesn't allow me to configure env variables in cluster.  Is there another way?

Comment: Oh I see, if you can't manage environment variables for the cluster. You can still work with Databricks secret. You can read more here: https://docs.databricks.com/security/secrets/index.html - so basically, you can create the same secret name but different values on both prod and dev